# HTML: how to prevent moving focus from element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several elements with `tabindex` attribute. When I click on any area of the page outside of them, they lose focus.

**Current Behaviour** - In *regular desktop applications*, if an element is not focusable, clicking on it doesn't move focus from a previous focused element.

But In HTML it's not the case: my focusable elements always lose focus, even if I click on elements with no `tabindex`.

**Required Behaviour** - Is it possible to prevent the above behaviour in HTML? I want my elements to lose focus only when I click on other focusable elements like its having in desktop application as I mentioned above.

Comment: it looks wired can you put the code/? @troorl

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort of hack and can be implemented in a better way.

#### Logic

- Create a global variable `lastSelectedInput` to store `id` of last visited element.
- Add a class to define boundary.
- Add a click event on body and if `event.path` does not contains boundary element, call focus of `lastSelectedInput`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/vnyqv144/3/)

#### Code

```js
(function() {
  var lastSelectedInput = "";

  function bodyClick(e) {
    var inside = false;
    for (var i in e.path) {
      if (e.path[i].className == "content") inside = true;
    }
    if (!inside) {
      document.getElementById(lastSelectedInput).focus();
    }
  }

  function inputFocus(e) {
    lastSelectedInput = e.target.id;
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  function registerEvents() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", bodyClick);

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].onfocus = inputFocus;
    }
  }

  registerEvents();
})();
```

```css
.content {
  margin: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text" id="txt1">
    <input type="text" id="txt2">
    <input type="text" id="txt3">
    <input type="text" id="txt4">
    <input type="text" id="txt5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This restores focus to the previous element (with a noticeable flicker) instead of preventing focus.